# Showing setup log info from the @BeforeTest annotation in a TestNG test

Tags: java, logging, output, testng

I'm developing some Selenium WebDriver tests in Java with testNg. I have a base class that launches the browser, navigates to a login page and logs me in. The method that does this in the base class is annotated with `@BeforeTest`. All my test classes extend this base class.

I've included some `Reporter.log("...")` calls in the `@BeforeTest` annotated method to log that the initial login was successful. However none of this output is appearing in the output files.

My question is: How can I include `@BeforeTest` annotated method's `Reporter.log()` output in the output file?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing it is to generate a log String of information in your dataprovider (during setup) , and then pass the string of log info to the `@Test` method using the Object[] parameter (optional TestNG method to the `@BeforeTest` and/or `@Test` methods).   Then, your @BeforeTest method has access to that string and can print it out using Reporter.log.

So, in other words, you wont be able to get any @Configuration methods to show output on a test (as designed I think) BUT anything you do within a DataProvider could be passed forward to the `@Test` method and/or @Before configuration methods.

Another way you could do it is to keep a String variable in the test class that keeps log info in it.  Then, during setup, save setup info to that string and then during the @Test method, access it and print it to the test output using `Reporter.log(string, true);` .

This just amounts to a circumstantial workaround that I would say you shouldn't do.  If you really think you need to show setup information in test log output, I would recommend really thinking about WHY you think you need to do that since it probably means your doing something unusual and not common practice.